# how to implements try-catch with asm?

Tags: java

i am new to asm,now i want to catch exception for per method in a class,trying to implement by myself and searching by google,but failed,who can write a full example for me?

```
       MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature,
                exceptions);
        mv.visitCode();
        Label lTryBlockStart = new Label();
        Label lTryBlockEnd = new Label();
        Label lCatchBlockStart = new Label();
        Label lCatchBlockEnd = new Label();
        // set up try-catch block for RuntimeException
        mv.visitTryCatchBlock(lTryBlockStart, lTryBlockEnd, lCatchBlockStart,
                "java/lang/Exception");
        mv.visitLabel(lTryBlockStart);
        // code to call the method goes here
        // mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
        // mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, this.name, name, desc);

        mv.visitLabel(lTryBlockEnd);
        mv.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, lCatchBlockEnd); // when here, no exception was
                                                // thrown, so skip exception
                                                // handler
        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
        mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, this.name, name, desc);
        // exception handler starts here, with RuntimeException stored on the
        // stack
        mv.visitLabel(lCatchBlockStart);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 1); // store the RuntimeException in local
                                    // variable 1
        // here we could for example do e.printStackTrace()
        mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1); // load it
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Exception",
                "printStackTrace", "()V");

        // exception handler ends here:
        mv.visitLabel(lCatchBlockEnd);
        mv.visitEnd();`
```

i failed to run those code,it throws a strange exception every time

Comment: "it throws a strange exception". Could you be a bit more specific about that?

Comment: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Field "save" in class com/duang/framework/aop/ServiceTest_tmp has illegal signature "()V",

Comment: "save" is  the one of methods in that class,but it shows "save" is a field here,i can't understand.

Comment: don't see where it's called/used in the code you posted

Comment: @z10030313335, "who can write a full example for me?" example of what? Do you want the simple try-catch block? e.g. try {your code here} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace()}

Comment: yes,i want to a simple example for try-catch-block with asm.

Comment: sorry,my english is poor,so i can't  express it well .